# Object not Saving in Heroku

Tags: swift, xcode, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to get my application to save in Heroku but this internal error keeps appearing in Xcode.

6-07-09 12:01:40.636 ParseStarterProject-Swift[4543:5272824] [Error]: {"code":1,"message":"Internal server error."} (Code: 1, Version: 1.12.0)

Object has been saved.

Nothing is saving in Heroku when I run my application in XCode but this appeared above the Collections:

To connect using the mongo shell:

mongo ds023054.mlab.com:23054/heroku_010b13wk -u -p

To connect using a driver via the standard MongoDB URI (what's this?):
mongodb://(redacted)@ds023054.mlab.com:23054/heroku_010b13wk

The build succeeded and there was no problems under "Issues" in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to to create another entry in your heroku settings : 
Go to "reveal config vars"
add a new key call DATABASE_URI --> and the value should be the same as your MONGODB_URI. Then save and compile your Xcode project. You shouldn't get that error anymore and the object would be created in your Collections in MLab website.
Source : [Follow the link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example/issues/163)